# How can I check my audio files for integrity?

Tags: audio

I've found that audio files seem to degrade slightly over time (10 years +), and I'm looking 
for a tool to check the integrity of those, and say, "yip, it's all there and good!".

I need something that checks:

- MP3
- WAV
- WMA
- AAC
- FLAC
- Monkey Audio

I've seen [MP3Check](http://jo.ath.cx/soft/mp3check/). It's good, but it only works on MP3s.

Comment: Please note that there is a difference between "integrity as in comform to the MP3 standard" and "integrity as in the file's checksum matches those of a database", tools that don't do online look-ups are of the former while those that take a footprint or check-sum are of the latter...

Answer (score 5):

- Foobar with the file integrity verifier [might do the trick](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_verifier).
- The Flac encoder will [check a file with the -t arguement](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=49487)
- You might also want to look at comparing the files against the [accuraterip](http://www.accuraterip.com/) or [cuetools](http://www.cuetools.net/wiki/CUETools_Database) database.

That being said, digital is digital, there's no reason they should degrade over time unlike analogue media.

Comment: That what puzzles me, the degradations. You'd expect being digital that they would be flawless, but theyre degraded. 12 years old audio files, and some are duff. I think it is something to do with Maxtor drives, which I used for a while.  I'll take a look at the Foobar etc.

Comment: Digital files may degenerate through the means of incremental bit rot. This may be caused by hardware glitches, software glitches (while tagging).

Comment: You unlikely want to use foobar2000 for that purpose - it just skips broken files when adding them from a playlist or directory. Sad but true.